# Spring + hibrnate = getting error while creating session fectory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, spring-security

I am using hibernate with spring.
I am getting following error while calling getCurrentSession method

```
protected Session getCurrentSession(){
   return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>    (JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:87)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:254)
   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1609)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:973)
```

I have searched alot and check all answer given on stackoverflow but not able to solve problem :( can any one help me why I am facing such error.

I am getting error when calling /campaign method

My Controller class is :

```
package com.nativeunlock.security.controller;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.nativeunlock.dto.CampaignEntity;
import com.nativeunlock.service.ICampaignService;
import com.nativeunlock.service.IUserService;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    IUserService userServices;

    @Autowired
    ICampaignService campaignService;


    @Secured("ROLE_OPERATION")
    @RequestMapping(value="/campaign", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String campaign(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {

        try {   

            List<CampaignEntity> userEntity = campaignService.getCampaignList();
            System.out.println(userEntity.size());

            String name = principal.getName();
            model.addAttribute("username", name);
            return "campaign";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return login(model, principal);
        }       
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_OPERATION")
    @RequestMapping(value="/addCampaign", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addCampaign(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {       
        try {           
            return "addCampaign";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return login(model, principal);
        }       
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {

        if(principal != null) {
            return campaign(model, principal);          
        }
        return "login_page";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginError", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

        return login(model, null);

    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {

        return login(model, null);

    }  
}
```

my service class :

```
package com.nativeunlock.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.nativeunlock.dao.ICampaignDao;
import com.nativeunlock.dto.CampaignEntity;

@Component
public class CampaignService implements ICampaignService {

    @Autowired
    ICampaignDao CampaignDao;

    @Override
    public List<CampaignEntity> getCampaignList() {

        return CampaignDao.getCampaignList();
    }

}
```

my dao class is :

```
package com.nativeunlock.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.nativeunlock.dto.CampaignEntity;

import org.hibernate.Query;

@Component
public class CampaignDao implements ICampaignDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;


    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("SessionFactory has not been set on DAO before usage");
        } 
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getCurrentSession(){
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public Query getNamedQuery(String queryName){
        return getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<CampaignEntity> getCampaignList() {     
        final Query clientQuery = getNamedQuery(CampaignEntity.GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY);
        return (List<CampaignEntity>) clientQuery.list();
    }

}
```

my entity class is

```
package com.nativeunlock.dto;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = CampaignEntity.GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY,
            query = "from CampaignEntity campaign"
    )     
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class CampaignEntity {

    public static final String GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY ="SiteURLs.getCampaignList";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int campain_id;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "no_of_views")   
    private int no_of_views;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "video_url") 
    private int video_url;      

}
```

my dispacher servlet is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nativeunlock.**" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:common.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="${datasource.class}">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.nativeunlock.dao.**"/>       
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetUrl" />
    </bean>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <security:global-method-security
        jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans>
```

My log is :

```
Mar 02, 2015 12:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 02, 2015 12:51:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 02, 2015 12:51:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Mar 02, 2015 12:51:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Audience-Box] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1609)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:973)
    at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getCurrentSession(CampaignDao.java:37)
    at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getNamedQuery(CampaignDao.java:41)
    at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getCampaignList(CampaignDao.java:47)
    at com.nativeunlock.service.CampaignService.getCampaignList(CampaignService.java:23)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:36)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
    at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
```

Comment: What's your getSessionFactory method?

Comment: @vimal

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  if (sessionFactory == null){
   throw new IllegalStateException("SessionFactory has not been set on DAO before usage");
  } 
  return sessionFactory;
 }


It is returning session object

Comment: And are you sure that you are not going in recursion through out the code?

Comment: I think no but I can share my classes if you want

Comment: Post it then with full stacktrace..!!

Comment: Why do you call `getCurrentSession` a method that doesn't get the current session, but opens a new one? Masochism?

Comment: @VimalBera done vimal

Comment: Also show more of your stacktrace - it's rather unlikely you'll get a `StackOverflowError` from a 6-level call-hierarchy!

Comment: login() calls campain(), which calls login(), which calls campaign(), which calls login(), etc. Doesn't seem to have much to do with Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: Like @JBNizet said, basically you have recursion in your code. Meaning, your code never stops at any point. Your `principal` is never null on login which then sends it into the campaign method which in turn throws an exception (**the important one**) which in turn goes into the login method, and this goes on ad infinitum

Comment: remove `     } catch (Exception e) {
            return login(model, principal);
        }       ` so that we can see real exception and you won't fall in recursion

Comment: Hi @JBNizet

after removing catch blog that problem get solved but now I am getting one another problem that is 

org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: getCampaignList
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSess
ionImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:137
1)
        at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getNamedQuery(CampaignDao.java:41)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you call the below two functions recursively within each other.

```
at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:61)
at com.nativeunlock.security.controller.LoginController.campaign(LoginController.java:42)
```

You don't have to do this as your controller is already secured with the annotation `@Secured("ROLE_OPERATION")` So if there is any requirement for authorization, Spring MVC will automatically call the login controller. All you have to do is to configure the logic contoller action in the configuration file. (or in annotations)

I read your comment on your real issue after you removed the recursion, That is

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: getCampaignList at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSess ionImpl.java:154) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getNamedQuery(SessionImpl.java:137 1) at com.nativeunlock.dao.CampaignDao.getNamedQuery(CampaignDao.java:41)
```

This is because of this line

```
public static final String GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY ="SiteURLs.getCampaignList";
```

You have to make sure that what ever the logic you are trying to implement there is correct. Recheck `SiteURLs.getCampaignList`. Hopefully that shouldn't be exist in the application.